# Imported CSS still available in child components

Tags: vue.js, sass

I imported SCSS files in my root component while using `scoped`:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@use "@/styles/_variables";
@use "@/styles/layout/_borders";
@use "@/styles/components/_buttons";
@use "@/styles/components/_customdropdown";
@use "@/styles/base/_typography";
@use "@/styles/base/_backgrounds";
@use "@/styles/_loader.scss";
```

So I expect the CSS not being available in child components cause styles should be encapsulated and not inherited to these children. But using classes from those files still works and are taking effect. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: For me, import SCSS like that will never get scoped because Vue's engine will only focus on it's own style (inside of `<style>`). I may be wrong but for me, this is a totally fine behavior. Maybe modules could help: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

Comment: I'm not a SASS expert tho, so don't hesitate to double check my opinion. Let's see if somebody else comes here.